# I need an excel formula to lookup a column and return value

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-statements, cell

I need cell C2 to lookup B2 for value 'SUSP' and return value as 'Suspended' in C2. If B2 is not value 'SUSP' then lookup A2 and return same value in C2[image]

Comment: So you tag vlookup, but what have you done to apply it? We like to see effort on here. You can also check out index() with match(). Note Excel has good explanations for vlookup, hlookup, lookup and xlookup (depending on your Excel version).

Comment: Seems to be a condition, not a lookup: =IF(B2="SUSP","Suspended",A2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter this into C2 and then drag the formula down to all relevant rows:

`=IF(B2="SUSP","Suspended",A2)`

Comment: great thanks. what if I wanted to combine this VLOOKUP =VLOOKUP(A2,Lookup!AB:AC,2,0) with the condition =IF(B2="SUSP","Suspended",A2). So if SUSP is not found in B2 look in the 'Lookup' tab in columns AB and return value from AC if AB has a value next to it in AC.

Comment: In your lookup, do you always want to return the looked-up value in AC or do you only want to return the value when there is something there (the cell is not blank)? And if it is blank then it should return A2?